# allocate shared_ptr in a function

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I need to create a function that returns an allocated shared_ptr variable. is this the correct way?

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > sharePtr;

void createPtr(sharePtr &p)
{
    p = sharePtr(new std::vector<char>);
}

void test()
{
     sharePtr p;
     createPtr(p);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. But why not write just:

```
sharedPtr createPtr()
{
    return sharePtr(new std::vector<char>);
}

void test()
{
     sharePtr p = createPtr();
}
```

? This can be faster than your version, and faster even more with a compiler supporting move semantics.

It's also recommended to use `make_shared` instead of direct `new`:

```
sharedPtr createPtr()
{
    return make_shared<std::vector<char>>();
}
```

because it can avoid the memory allocation for the reference counter.

Comment: The counter-recommendation for `make_shared` is that if the object is large (which `vector` isn't), and if you're using weak pointers (which this code doesn't), then `make_shared` might waste more memory than is worth it for the time/memory it saves. Thought I'd mention it, though.

Comment: @Steve: agree. counter-counter-recommendation: `make_shared` is exception safe, what's not a problem in this code. BTW, do typical implementations check if the object is large and do two allocations in that case?

Comment: @ybungalobill: no idea, and I'm not sure it would even be wise for `make_shared` to do that, since most shared_ptr-controlled objects never will be weakly referenced anyway.

Comment: @Steve: could you explain why that is? What does the weak_ptr do to waste memory in the make_shared but not in the usual case? Is this documented somewhere (in Boost docs or STD papers)?

Comment: @Fabio: if an object is referred to only by `weak_ptr` s, not `shared_ptr` s, then in the case of separate allocation, the object will be deleted and only the management node retained (to tell the `weak_ptr` s that the object is gone if anyone tries to `lock` any of them). In the case of single allocation containing both the object and the management data, the object can be destroyed, but the allocation can't be freed. So more memory is kept around for longer, until all weak pointers are gone.

Comment: the ref counter can't be freed until all shared *and* weak pointers are destroyed. And if you use `make_shared`, the ref counter and the object itself are part of the same allocation, so you can't free one without the other. This means that as long as you have a weak pointer using this ref counter, the object itself can't be deleted, even if its ref count is 0.

Comment: @Steve, @jalf: Thanks, nice catch! And I suppose this is by desingn, since shrinking the memory in-place is not supported by the standard, and reallocation would break the weak_ptrs. Hmpf, very ugly situation.

Comment: @Fabio: it's not all that bad. For large classes that will be weakly referenced you can either (a) avoid `make_shared`, (b) use pimpl, (c) buy more RAM, so there are plenty of options. The referenced object can have its destructor called as soon as the last `shared_ptr` goes, so with a pimpl class (or `vector`) all the hefty stuff is freed, leaving a stub that increases the size of the refcount node a bit, but not much.

Comment: @Steve: I understand. As always "another indirection solves the problem" :) I still don't like the situation, because it makes the abstraction leak, and I need to manually provide a workaround. I know that this is a corner case, and not likely to come to haunt one often, but still.

Comment: @Fabio: if you don't want the abstraction to leak, then you can use a simpler helper function of your own devising, which doesn't use a single allocation, just does `return shared_ptr<T>(new T(args));`. You could then write something which uses type traits or `sizeof(T)` to choose between them. Building optimizations into helper functions is liable to cause leaks in the functional part of the abstraction, since `make_shared` is designed to do two things.

Comment: @Steve: Of course, but then I won't get the optimization of only one allocation. I am probably disopointed by this because of two things: 1. make_shared is great it allows a external abstraction to be as efficient as a intrusive one. 2. The "memory leak" would not be necessary if http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2045.htm had been adopted.